# What are the differences between WebView.Source and WebView.Navigate?

Tags: webview, uwp

In documentation it is stated that we should use `WebView.Navigate` from code, but I want to understand why. What are the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my tests there does not seem to be any difference between these two approaches in terms of navigation - both create a history entry (so `GoBack` works properly), both support HTTP/HTTPS URI as well as local files using `ms-appdata:` and `ms-appx:` protocols.

The only difference I can think of then is the fact that `Source` allows you to read back the currently displayed URI (in addition to setting it) and it supports data-binding, so you can use it in MVVM manner.

Comment: So setting the source always also navigates to that source? in my app it sometimes happen that setting the source leaves the webview white, and i cant catch it in onnavigationfailed, ornavigationcompleted or even in try catch.

Comment: That is actually interesting... It should always navigate, if you can create a repro on GitHub for example, I could try it on my PC to see what is happening and maybe we could then report it to the UWP team :-)

Comment: Thank you, I am currently trying to reproduce it, but seems like it only occurs on one raspi, and not each time i run it, but like one in twenty times. Could it possibly mean problem with the website itself?

Comment: It could, however it is quite weird anyway... Does it happen with a different website like Google?

Comment: yes it is different website which is quite buggy actually. but it is strange nonetheless