# Refreshing webview after setting source or navigating cancels the navigation in UWP

Tags: webview, uwp

This is my `mainpage.xaml.cs` :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        wv.Source = new Uri("https://www.youtube.com");
        //wv.Refresh();
    }
}
```

this works - as soon as i run the app YouTube is loaded. But when I uncomment the `wv.Refresh` it stops working - i see only white background. Also happens when I use `wv.Navigate` instead of `wv.Source`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have good questions about `WebView` :-D .

I have debugged it and it seems that even though the `Source` is set to the URI, internally the `WebView` still is pointing to `about:blank` page and refresh comes too early so the navigation to your URI is cancelled and instead the blank page is refreshed.

I have come up with the following code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    webview.NavigationStarting += Webview_NavigationStarting;
}

private void Webview_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Navigating " + args.Uri);
}

private void SetNextSource()
{        
    var uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
    Debug.WriteLine("Setting " + uri);
    webview.Source = uri;
    webview.Refresh();
    Debug.WriteLine("Set  " + webview.Source);
}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Sample run]

As you can see in the output, the refresh completely ignored the `Source` property and most likely used some kind of internal URI.

So to fix your problem, you could just hook up the `NavigationCompleted` event and do the `Refresh()` in there instead - as by that time, the `WebView` will actually finish loading the page and will even internally be pointing to the newly set URI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again. But as i mentioned in previous post in comments (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481593/what-are-the-differences-between-webview-source-and-webview-navigate) NavigationCompleted doesnt catch any errors when white page remains hanging and thats where i wanted to call      Refresh(). This question came up when i wanted to refresh after setting the url each time, but its even worse.